# Cannot load jsonp data into datatables

Tags: datatables

I am creating a datatables as follows:

```js
var table = $('#details').DataTable({    
   "ajax": {
       "url": "http://myapi/code",           
       "dataType": "jsonp",
       "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [{
       "data": "name"
     },{
       "data": "initials"
     }]
});
```

and my data structure is:

```js
{  
   "name":"john Doe",
   "initials":"JD"      
}
```

But datatables keeps on displaying "No matching records found".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data structure should be an array of items, ie `[ {...}, {...},...]`

Comment: doh, what a goose. Thanks davidkonrad